# Is there a sensible way to implement depth peeling on OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Since OpenGL ES 2.0 lacks `GL_ALPHA_TEST` and `glAlphaFunc`, the regular way of implementing depth peeling for transparent object obviously doesn't work. Theoretically I could use `if (alpha < 1) discard;` in my fragment shader, but as it's a branch, I'm afraid it might be too slow.

Are there any other ways to approach this?

Does anybody have experience with the performance `if (alpha < 1) discard;` compared to just accepting the cost of the overdraw in back-to-front rendering?

Edit: Although it seems that I describe pure alpha testing above, my goal is actually to achieve something similar to depth peeling or early-z. The issue I'm solving is that with back-to-front rendering I get a huge amount of overdraw on opaque pixels. So I want to render in two passes. First is front-to-back with alpha-testing turned on with alpha func `==1` (this is the "depth-peeling" or "early-z" pass). Second is back-to-front with alpha blending and depth-testing turned on.

Comment: Are you sure you mean depth peeling? Depth peeling is a technique for achieving order independent transparency, but you say you're already doing back-to-front rendering. I wonder if you meant to say alpha testing instead.

Comment: You're right. I want something like alpha testing although my goal is very similar to depth peeling (or early-z). I have no problem with rendering front-to-back or back-to-front, but performance suffers greatly with back-to-front rendering. On a heavy scene I may get an average of 8x overdraw. Those are tens of millions of pixel shader calls wasted, when only a small amount of them are semi-transparent. So I want to draw front-to-back on my first pass with alpha testing, to fill the depth buffer and then draw back-to-front on my second pass, this time with depth testing and alpha-blending on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general avoid heavy use of `discard` at all costs. It definitely isn't a general purpose replacement for early-zs testing and causes some horrible issues with data dependencies between pixels (you can't resolve the depth value with confidence until late-z because you don't know ahead of time if the shader will actually discard a fragment or not).

You don't say exactly what your use case is, but if it's 2D rendering layers of opaque sprites then one good fix is to to adjust your geometry per sprite into two batches - really opaque stuff, which can use depth testing with blending disabled (render front-to-back), and blended stuff which you draw in a second pass (render back-to-front with depth testing enabled, but depth writes disabled).

This blog is a good outline of the technique:

- https://community.arm.com/groups/arm-mali-graphics/blog/2015/11/19/mali-performance-7-accelerating-2d-rendering-using-opengl-es

If your content is arbitrary 3D content which is alpha tested then I fear you are going to hit pain which ever way you try, as discards are never really that efficient.

Comment: My case is indeed 2D and using geometry over the opaque parts is an alternative I'm considering, but It's much more complex than the example in the link. The content albeit 2D is not sprites, but complex 2D meshes... so I guess it might qualify as arbitrary 3D content. Generating the "early z" geometry for those meshes Is going to be very hard. Manually drawing it is a lot of effort too. I guess I'm going test the discard path and if the results are not satisfactory, try to figure out how to go about the opaque geometry.

Comment: Yeah, for arbitrary meshes without some means to preprocess then that technique doesn't work easily - I've never tried to preprocess the textures live on a platform. One word or warning is that the impact of `discard` on performance can be somewhat erratic across GPU vendors and hardware revisions, so you might want to try it on a couple of devices.

Comment: So I did some experiments and while for my case `discard` did provide a small performance gain, it was't enough. I'll be using custom geometry for depth testing

Comment: @solidpixel What about `clip`?

Comment: User controllable clip panes don't exist in ES 2.0.